# Position a element to bottom-right corner on any device using Anime.js

Tags: css, anime.js

```js
function goBottomRight(){
    
  anime({
    targets: '.btn',
    translateX:  240,
    translateY:  320,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  }).play;
   
   

}
```

```html
<button class='btn' onclick='goBottomRight()'>Click Me</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
```

I am attempting to create a animation using `anime.js` where you click an element it will go to the bottom-right corner of the page but at the same time i need it to be responsive for desktop and mobile.

Here is my code so far.

```
function goBottomRight(){

  anime({
    targets: '.btn',
    translateX:  240,
    translateY:  320,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  }).play;

}
```

Well above code works on a fix screen resolution but how can i ensure that its always go to the bottom-right corner of the page?

Comment: Well you’d have to _calculate_ what translation values you need, by determining what the element’s current position in relation to the viewport is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your element to be `position: fixed;`

Position fixed will cause your element to be always visible on that position. Do keep in mind `z-index` because if it isn't the last element in your document it might vanish under other elements or elements that have a higher z-index.

Then animate it to position: `right:0px; bottom: 0px;`

This will then give the desired behavior on any screen.

```js
function goBottomRight()
{
  var element = document.querySelector('.btn');
  element.style.position = 'fixed';  
  anime({
    targets: element,
    right:  '0px',
    bottom:  '0px',
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  });
}
```

```html
<button class='btn' onclick='goBottomRight()'>Click Me</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
```